# $\{x \in l^2|\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i \text{ converges}\} $ is a closed subspace of $l^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $S = \{x \in l^2|\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i \text{ converges}\} $. Is $S$ a closed subspace of $l^2$?

It is easy to prove that it is a subspace, but how can I prove/disprove it is closed?

Thanks

Comment: Try $x^{(n)}_i=\frac1i$ if $i\leqslant n$, $x^{(n)}_i=0$ if $i\geqslant n+1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S$ is not closed. In fact $S$ contains every sequence that is eventually zero, that is:

$$\{x\in l^2|\exists n \,\mbox{  s.t. } x_i=0 \,\,\,\forall i\ge n\}\subset S.$$

Now the set $\{x\in l^2|\exists n \,\mbox{  s.t. } x_i=0 \,\,\,\forall i\ge n\}$ is dense in $l^2$, hence also $S$ is dense in $l^2$ and $S$ is not closed.